# Does HTML5 remove the distinction between strict and transitional?

Tags: html

From what I have read, it appears that HTML5 removes the distinction between strict and transitional (always strict now). I have not been able to find it specifically mentioned anywhere, only implied. Is this the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the (only) [DOCTYPE for HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/syntax.html#the-doctype):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

That's it.  So yes, there's no difference between "strict" and "transitional".

Comment: Nb. XHTML5 can be used as well, but apparently it doesn't need a doctype

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.  Transitional and Strict only apply to XHTML 1.0 and HTML 4.01.

Comment: Transitional and strict applied to HTML 4.01 as well. 4.01 also had "Frameset". Strict disallowed elements like `<font>` and attributes like `width` and `height`...

Comment: They do not only apply to XHTML. They apply to HTML 4.01 as a standard as well. Transitional doctype in HTML 4.01 allows the use of depreciated elements while strict does not.

Comment: Sorry - but Transitional and Strict also apply to HTML 4.01, so not just XHTML: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp

Comment: Good point; I updated the answer to be more accurate (though, that bit is orthogonal to the question).

Answer (score 1):

From what I have gathered so far html5 has some sloppy allowances, for instance, you can tag upper or lower case. It will not necessarily flag certain fudging as xhtml 1.1 will. I suspect this can lead into problems down the line for the casual/sloppy coder.

I code in xhtml strict.  I would advise anyone learning html to learn strict coding practices - it will teach you how to code consistently and accurately, and how to problem solve succinctly, and to be better prepared as xml standards open up for more and more practical use.
I cannot stress how glad I am I started coding strict.
If you search on "is html5 strict" (the truth is out there) you will find tones of what I am saying reflected/shared in the more educated circles (imho), so I think my remarks are fairly sound.  You will also find good advice on maintaining your tried and true xhtml coding while stretching your legs with (x)html5.  (If you don't know why I added the (x) there, then you are not done searching ;^)  Try searching html5 + xml  ;^)
HTH, Cheers.